# List all raster layers in Geopackage using pyqgis

Tags: raster, qgis, pyqgis, geopackage

With the following code it is super easy to list all vector layers in a geopackage:

```
my_gpkg = r'PATH_TO_GEOPACKAGE'
gpkg_layers = [l.GetName() for l in ogr.Open(my_gpkg )]
```

Is there also a way to list all raster layers in a geopackage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could solve my problem with the help of this post: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287997/counting-the-number-of-layers-in-a-geopackage

And here is my solution:

```
import sqlite3

my_gpkg = r'PATH_TO_GEOPACKAGE'
            
sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect(my_gpkg)
cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()

# the table gpkg_contents is mandatory in every geopackage
sqlite_select_query = """Select table_name from gpkg_contents where data_type = 'tiles'"""
cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
records = cursor.fetchall()
raster_layers = []
for row in records:
    layer_name = row[0]
    raster_layers.append(layer_name)
            
print('These are the raster layers in your geopackage: {}'.format(raster_layers))

cursor.close()
```